# JqGrid colMoldel formatter variable

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

(version free jqgrid 4.13.6)

I have some datetime column which I defined as {... formatter:"date" ... }, that's OK.

Now, in some cases, depending of the field value, I need to use another custom formatter. 
Since formatter:"date" is jqgrid native, I don't know how to solve this situation.

Example: normally the field value is a datetime, such "2017-04-18 10:06", which is OK for formatter:"date". But, in some few cases, the value is a string, such as "ALL DATES". Only in these cases, the formatter must be "myCustomFormatter",
NOT formatter:"date", because I don't want to modify the jqgrid native "date" function to consider this special case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to examine [the lines](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.13.6/js/grid.base.js#L3368-L3371) of the code of free jqGrid to see where there is a difference between call of the custom formatter and a prededefined formatter (like `formatter: "date"`):

```
...
} else if (isFunction(cm.formatter)) {
    v = cm.formatter.call(ts, cellval, opts, rwdat, act);
} else if ($.fmatter) {
    v = $.fn.fmatter.call(ts, cm.formatter, cellval, opts, rwdat, act);
} else {
...
```

It means that to call the `formatter: "date"` from the custom formatter you need just use

```
 formatter: function (cellValue, options, rowObject, action) {
     return $.fn.fmatter.call(this, "date", cellValue, options, rowObject, action);
 },
 unformat: function (cellValue, options, cell) {
     return $.unformat.date.call(this, cellValue, options.formatoptions);
 }
```

The above code just forwards calls to the formatter date. See https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/gq5hxtnc/.

What you will need to do finally is to modify the above code on custom formatters to forward the calls to `formatter: "date"` not always, but if, for example, the input isn't the string `"ALL DATES"`.

Comment: thanks!  So, I understand that " $.fn.fmatter " is a jquery function created by jqgrid, containing all predefined formatters? It shouldn't be more correct to create it within the $.jqgrid scope? Something like $.jqgrid.fmatter or such...

Comment: @Aberel: **Any** global method would be good. One can't say that `$.jqgrid` is "more correct" as `$.fn.fmatter`. On of the goasl of free jqGrid is providing **backwards compatibility** with the previous versions of jqGrid 4.x. Old jqGrid uses formatter plugin (see [the commens](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.14.0/js/jquery.fmatter.js#L2-L6)) and I *hold* the same structure. You can see [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.14.0/ts/free-jqgrid.d.ts#L1645-L1652) other scopes registered inside of jQuery: `$.jqm`, `$.jqDnR`, `$.jqm`, `$.fmatter` and `$.unformat`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use custom **formatter** for the column like following.

```
formatter: function(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
    var date = new Date(cellvalue);

    if(isNaN(date.getFullYear())){
        return cellvalue;
    } else {
        return date.getDate()  + "/" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + date.getFullYear();
    }
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/HJema/600/)**

Comment: Azim, thanks for your solution, but I want to use the prededefined formatter "date" in most cases, except those where the value is a specific string (ie. "ALL DATES"). So, I think the Oleg's answer would be better for my needs. Regards.